# What is the purpose of putting nameof in CreatedAtAction in Web Api Controller?

Tags: c#

This is the [sample code from microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]

public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> CreateAsync(Product product)
{
    if (product.Description.Contains("XYZ Widget"))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    await _repository.AddProductAsync(product);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = product.Id }, product);
}
```

What is the usage of `nameof` here? When I look at it, `GetById` is another action method. But I am not sure why we need that.

Comment: Do you know what `nameof` is/does?

Answer (score 1):

In RESTful API, a POST is supposed to return the route to the created object, so that callers can know the ID value that has been assigned server-side.

To reduce the amount of boilerplate code, there is the `CreatedAtAction` method, which figures out the route to the Controller's `GetById` method in a generic, implementation-agnostic method - via reflection.

Under the hood, it is an invoke-by-name pattern, therefore the name of the method to reflect on is needed, and this is what the `nameof` operator achieves here: The type of the first parameter in the `CreateAtAction` method is `System.String`.